# Regular Expression, always capital letter after "-"

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have a regular expresion like:

```
@"^[A-Z][a-z\-\']+((\s[A-Z][a-z\-\'\.]*)?)+(\s[A-Z][a-z\-\'\.]*)?"
```

which allows a name to be written like Name, Name LastName or Name LastName LastName. I added the special characters `', -,.` for special names. But i want to add the condition that after the '`-`' the letter could be capital. But only after the dash. Nowhere else in the word, execptin the beggining. Any ideas?

Comment: [There is no Regex for people's names. Don't try to write one either](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

Comment: Replace `\s` with `(\s|-)` so it matches a space or a slash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex would meet your dash criteria, although I can't speak for other naming variations that might be prevented.

```
^(?:[“"]?[A-Za-z][a-z]*["”'.,]?(-[A-Z][a-z]+)?(?: (?!$))?)+$
```

It matches the following:

```
Leonardo da Vinci
Leonardo di ser Piero da Vinci
Tony “The Tiger”
Tony "The Tiger"
Cynthia Ann Stephanie Lauper Thornton
Madonna
John McClane
Notorious B.I.G.
John Thomas
Mary-Kate Olsen
JP Morgan
O'Doul's Amber
```

It does NOT match the following:

```
Mortimer Snerd-
Bobby Bones-BReaker
```